# Is it necessary to use the "." symbol in the purr map() function

Tags: r

When trying to read tweets from a text file that uses "|" as the separator, the following two code snippets give seemingly similar results:

```
bbc <- stringi::stri_read_lines(".../bbchealth.txt", 
                                     encoding = "auto") %>%
  map(str_split_fixed, "\\|", 3) %>%
  map_df(as_tibble)
```

and

```
bbc <- stringi::stri_read_lines(".../bbchealth.txt", 
                                     encoding = "auto") %>%
  map(., str_split_fixed, "\\|", 3) %>%
  map_df(., as_tibble)
```

My question is whether the "." symbol in the two map functions in the latter case, which presumably passes a list or vector, is necessary at all?

Comment: By default, it assumes the data is being passed on the from the lhs of `%>%`.  So, it is not really needed to specify the `.` unless you have a `print` statement i.e. `%>% {print("hello"); map(., str_split_fixed, "\\|", 3)}`

Comment: also interesting to note from @akrun's comment is that if you want to override the first argument being the evaluation of the LHS, you can enclose that part of the pipe in {}. For instance, if you would want to use the pre-tidyverse gsub (for which not the first but the last argument is the data), you would write `%>% {gsub(pattern, replacement, .)} %>%`. In this case, you need to explicitly use . to represent the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the pipe `%>%`, the first argument of the right-hand-side expression is the result of the left-hand-side one. This can be bypassed by using `.` to indicate where the LHS expression should go instead, if it shouldn't be the first expression. For example:

```
a<-1
a %>% paste("3")
[1] "1 3"
a %>% paste("3",.)
[1] "3 1"
```

This is relevant in some functions where the first argument is not the data (e.g., base::Reduce), or if you want to use the result of the LHS somewhere else in the expression, as in the example above.

So if the LHS should be the first argument in the RHS expression, there's no need for the `.`.

BTW - `.` can also be used if for some reason you want to use the LHS more than once in your RHS expression:

```
a %>% paste(.,"3",.)
[1] "1 3 1"
```

Or, a slightly more realistic example:

```
a %>% ifelse(.==1,3,.)
[1] 3
a %>% ifelse(.!=1,3,.)
[1] 1
```

(and, as you can see, you can also use `.` to create boolean conditions).

Answer (score 1):

As the OP mentioned, the two set of codechunks gives the same result, as it knows the input being passed out from the lhs of `%>%`.  However, there are situations where we may need to explcitly specify the `.`.  Suppose, we have a `print` statement within one of the chains, then without specifying the `.` could create issues

```
bbc <- stringi::stri_read_lines(".../bbchealth.txt", 
                                 encoding = "auto") %>%
 {print("hello")
  map(., str_split_fixed, "\\|", 3)} %>%
  map_df(as_tibble)
```